How to convert numbers after the Radix Point from base 10 to base -2
I have been unable to find any documentation on any algorithm or method of converting fractional reparations from base 10 to base -2 (or any other negative base). While you can easaly convert from base -2 to base 10, how do you convert a number like 0.376 to a base -2 radix point approximation?
def Radix (number, base):
    global x
    remainder = ""
    while len(remainder) <= 5:
        number *= base
        remainder += str(abs(math.floor(number)))
        if number <= 0:
            number *= -1
            x = 1
        while number >= 1:
            number -= 1
        if x == 1:
            number *= -1
            x = 0
        print(remainder)
Radix((float(input("number"))*-1), -2)

This was a very rough first algorithm, it is able to convert certain numbers successfully, like 0.25 in base 10 to 0.01.
